# copy everything after matched pattern till end of each line

Tags: file-io

i have a file  like

> abcjjsdxsaxsaskjakjxas, sham nkhhjkllllhhghhkjlkll
>
> jjjusdiolsjshsnsjsusjus sham ooushsjsysghsjsjksksls
>
> ilsjsusynshshssjsjgsgtsttwfwgwywuwnwhww owuwywtwbwwh sham
>
> losuyeeegftgsyshshsh sjsisusns sisisusus lckcncncmcn owueyete
> sisuysyshsbs sham hdndhgdgebeheodjdjdhdgdgd
>
> loshsbvsgshjsjssmms  twrqeqqgtw wtwrfsxvxvzflld
> spsishdvd dkdididjd shsh shshsh llll sham iiiiyhh

I want to print everything after sham of each line into a different file.
I want the output line wise only. I have tried various things using awk in  unix.

Thanks,
sham

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: This definitely shouldn't have the 'design patterns' tag. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please tell us more exactly where you have a problem and what you have already tried. And please specify the programming language you are using.

Comment: U want to do this in unix by using awk or sed.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer here

awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/sham/)print $(i) $(i+1) $(i+2) $(i+3) $(i+4) $(i+5) $(i+6) $(i+7)}' file

u can adjust print cammand per ur requirement..